# Generate MS-project file with main tasks and milestones from excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I managed to make a nice script that can generate a MS-project file from selected tables in excel. I am now looking for help making it a bit more useful. I would like to insert milestones under each main task from a specific table in excel. Each main task has a corresponding table of milestones.

```
Sub MSPexport()

Dim pjapp As Object
Dim strValue, strWorktime, strMilestone As String
Dim newproj
Set pjapp = CreateObject("MSProject.application") 

If pjapp Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Project is not installed"
End
End If

pjapp.Visible = True
Set newproj = pjapp.Projects.Add
Set ActiveProject = newproj

pjapp.NewTasksStartOn

'insert tasks here

 For I = 3 To 8 'currently I am pointing to the range A3:A:8 - would like to make it a named range instead - ie "Maintasks" - how to do this?

    strValue = Worksheets("Planning").Range("A" & I)
    newproj.Tasks.Add (strValue)

    'Insert predecessor if not first task
    If I <> 3 Then
      newproj.Tasks(I - 2).Predecessors = (I - 3)
    End If

    'here I would like to insert milestones as subtasks

    For M = 3 to 5 ' this I also would like to be a named range and also I need to check for or lookup the correct main task and the corresponding milestone list
      strMilestone = Worksheets("Milestones").Range("C" & M)
        newproj.Tasks.Add (strMilestone)
        newproj.Tasks(M - 2).Duration = 0
        newproj.Tasks(M - 2).OutlineIndent
        newproj.Tasks(M - 2).Predecessors = (I - 26)
    Next M   
Next I

End Sub
```

The MS-Project should look like this when done:
[image: The MS-Project should look like this when done]

[image: Excel tables]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code updated to 1) use named ranges, and 2) insert the milestones:

```
Sub MSPexport()

Dim pjapp As Object
Dim newproj As Object

Set pjapp = CreateObject("MSProject.application")
If pjapp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Project is not installed"
    Exit Sub
End If
pjapp.Visible = True
Set newproj = pjapp.Projects.Add
pjapp.NewTasksStartOn

Dim rngMain As Range
Set rngMain = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Maintasks").RefersToRange
Dim MainTask As Range
Dim tskPredTaskMain As Object

For Each MainTask In rngMain.Cells
    Dim tskSummary As Object
    Set tskSummary = newproj.Tasks.Add(MainTask.Value)
    tskSummary.OutlineLevel = 1

    Dim rngMS As Range
    Set rngMS = ActiveWorkbook.Names(MainTask.Value & "_Milestones").RefersToRange
    Dim Milestone As Range
    Dim tskPredTaskMS As Object
    Set tskPredTaskMS = Nothing

    For Each Milestone In rngMS
        Dim tskMS As Object
        Set tskMS = newproj.Tasks.Add(Milestone.Value)
        ' use duration stored in days in column to the right
        tskMS.Duration = Milestone.Offset(, 1).Value * 8 * 60
        tskMS.OutlineLevel = 2

        If Not tskPredTaskMS Is Nothing Then
            tskMS.Predecessors = tskPredTaskMS.ID
        End If
        Set tskPredTaskMS = tskMS

    Next Milestone

    If Not tskPredTaskMain Is Nothing Then
        tskSummary.Predecessors = tskPredTaskMain.ID
    End If
    Set tskPredTaskMain = tskSummary

Next MainTask

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Rachel - thank you very much - works perfect. I have a few additional questions that I hope you can help me with also. I would like to add a duration to the main tasks from a table called MainTaskTime. Could you help me with the code for that too?

Comment: Since the Main Tasks end up being Summary tasks, their duration is determined by the milestone tasks under them; you cannot set the Duration field on a Summary task. Perhaps you will want to set durations on the milestone tasks instead.

Comment: Regarding the Footers, yes, different views will have different headers/footers so you need to identify which view when you use that method; the most commonly used view is Gantt Chart.

Comment: Could you add an example of setting the time of a milestone task based on a named range (for example "maintask_Milestones_duration")?

Comment: @JesperKindtLarsen code updated to show how you can use an adjacent cell containing the duration for the milestone tasks. Regarding errors with setting the header, start a new question, show what you've done and give details about the error.

Comment: Dear Rachel - again thank you very much for your help. I posted a new question regarding the pagesetup and removed comments about it in this post.